# combine several GIF horizontally - python

Tags: python, image, gif, python-imageio

I have two GIF files, and I want to combine them horizontally to be shown beside each other, and they play together.
They have equal frames.
I tried a lot online for a solution, but didn't find something which is supporting GIF. I think the `imageio` package supports gif, but I can't find a way to use it to combine two together
Simply, I want something like this example
[image]
Any ideas of doing so ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python

Comment: Hello @Carlo1585 Yes exactly, I checked this and tried it. But it doesn't support GIF format, it gave me two JPG beside each other

Comment: not sure about sorry, to be honest I never used imageio, but I'll try to investigate more. In any case I went to the imageio git project and I saw that there are still different issues with gif images so I advice you to have a look there.

Comment: No problem, thanks a lot. But apart from imageio, is there another way to do this task ?

Comment: Can't you use this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30932152/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Unfortunately, I don't have rights or authorization to install Magick. I know that this can be done easily by Magick, ffmpeg and so, but that's why I am trying to use a python script

Comment: How about this? https://gist.github.com/jonschoning/7216290

Comment: This is the library of reading, writing GIFs

Answer (score 4):

I would code something like this :

```
import imageio
import numpy as np    

#Create reader object for the gif
gif1 = imageio.get_reader('file1.gif')
gif2 = imageio.get_reader('file2.gif')

#If they don't have the same number of frame take the shorter
number_of_frames = min(gif1.get_length(), gif2.get_length()) 

#Create writer object
new_gif = imageio.get_writer('output.gif')

for frame_number in range(number_of_frames):
    img1 = gif1.get_next_data()
    img2 = gif2.get_next_data()
    #here is the magic
    new_image = np.hstack((img1, img2))
    new_gif.append_data(new_image)

gif1.close()
gif2.close()    
new_gif.close()
```

So the magic trick is to use the hstack numpy function. It will basically stack them horizontally. This only work if the two gif are the same dimensions.

Comment: `imageio` cannot write transparency layers to GIFs, which is what bit me. Stay away if you need that!