# How can I dynamically stack gifs horizontally to create one gif in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, python-imaging-library

What I need to do is combine two or more GIF files into one horizontally using Python. I thought about using PIL or ffmpeg but I could never really get anywhere. I found partial solutions on the internet, however they aren't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to add an uncertain amount of gifs to one horizontal strip gif. The sizes of each individual GIF are different, and the amount of GIFS being stacked horizontally changes depending on the user's input. Essentially a dynamic hstack filter for ffmpeg. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any mock visuals you can provide? I'm trying to think about this in my head and I'm not certain I see what you are trying to do. 

Also, if you can share what you've tried/how far you got with PIL and ffmpeg and why those didn't work for you that also gives info to assist.

Comment: Are you talking about animated GIFs, or simple, single images? Do you have an example, or mock-up of what you start with and what you expect to get as a result?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30932152/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, that is exactly what I need however I do not have access to ImageMagick as I am working on repl.it to create this. It doesn't allow me to install ImageMagick binaries, and there aren't any good bindings for it for Python I could use. I found Wand.py, but its a different API.

Comment: @JustinCarroll stackoverflow.com/a/30932152/2836621 basically describes what I need, with visual demos, however I do not have access to ImageMagick.